# What's the best way to optimise an url with spaces for LinkedIn share, using MVC Razor?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**Background**

I have an url to share on LinkedIn with a title parameter: `some title`.

To be able to add this title to an URL, the space(s) need to be replaced by %20, but apparently LinkedIn Share requires double encoding, so the `%` needs to be encoded as well.

That means that spaces become `%2520`.

If I manually correct my url like that, it's shared on my LinkedIn.

**What would work**

Thinking further on the above, I would get a LinkedIn Share url like so:

> https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url=http://example.com/entity/1?title=Some%2520title

This would work.

**However**

On my web page I'm using MVC Razor, and apparently HTML.Raw() decodes the `%2520` back to `%20`, which will be incorrect.

**Question**

What's the best way to print the desired URL in the correct way?

Comment: what about using URL-Shortener API to solve that !! .. you have many options (google, bitly ..

Comment: @AhmedRagheb: Sadly that's not a decision I can make right now, I just need to implement a very quick fix. Has to work as is.

Comment: check my answer, hope it solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was working in a News portal before and we created a Helper method to replace any space in string with underscore for sharing also to avoid this problem, And I think it is a good quick solution

```
public static string RemoveSpaceFromTitle(this string text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
       return text;

    return text.Replace(" ", "_");
}
```

Comment: This works, it's surprising though because I would expect that the page I'm sharing would then show `some_title` as text, but it doesn't. How come? Also, I think I run the risk of introducing incorrect data.

Comment: @Spikee stackoverflow doing that for question title and tags, it is a common trick to avoid this problem and if you check random sites you will find them doing that 

Ex: http://edition.cnn.com/2017/01/02/autos/9-luxury-cars-that-will-dominate-the-roads-in-2017

Comment: @Spikee If it works, please mark it as solved so other can use same answer